# Download repo project from GitHub

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to download a project from this git hub repo. I asking because there is no download button, so it is mean that this is impossible?

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/maven/demos/superjumper

Answer (score 3):

You should go back to its root level: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/maven.

And then you can find the download button. No git app is need to be installed.

[image]

---

Of course, if you have git app installed in your PC, you can simply run:

```
git clone https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx.git
```

Answer (score 2):

For this type of file, you have to install the Gib app and run this:

```
git clone https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx.git
```

You should be able to download it then. Good luck :)

You can also go to the directory before that. There should be a download button there.

Answer (score 0):

You were in a subdirectory of the project. Go back to the [project root](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/maven) and you will the download and clone actions.